# Remap cmd/option and ctrl/capslock in Windows 7 on MacBook with BootCamp

Tags: laptop, boot-camp

I'm having serious problems getting my keyboard remapping to work in Windows 7 on a MacBook with BootCamp.

I'd like to remap control key to capslock, and cmd (Windows key in bootcamp) to option (Alt in bootcamp), and option to cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**KeyTweak**](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/). Remap left control to left windows and vice versa if you want to exchange the functions of ctrl/cmd. The same applies to your own appetite.